# There are no methods that help me figure out why videos wont work on my website

Tags: html, video

I am trying to add a video to my website, but no matter what I do and What I try, it will not work. It will just show that it is loading and then shows a black screen. Here is the code I am using:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="lol.avi" type="video/avi">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I also tried videojs and it said, "The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.".

Thank You.

Comment: From what you are saying, there is no reason this should not work. Give us more info. What browser are you using? Where is the video located? Is JS enabled in your browser? Etc.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I am using chrome and javascript is enabled. The video is located in the same folder as the html document. I also tried to go to the files directory in chrome and it still shows the same broken video.

Comment: your problem is most likely .avi ... HTML5 video supports .mp4, .webm, and .ogg. See the subfeatures list on https://caniuse.com/#search=video

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you try to play an .avi container on HTML5 native video player. The problem is that HTML5 typically supports only very limited formats and codecs, as Offbeatmammal already writes.

By the way regarding to your title "the method that helps your figure out why videos wont work on your website" is what you already did: you try to load it and you got the error message that the format is not supported.

It basically depends on browser, OS and Version which exact combinations and detailed coding settings are supported, here is yet another list of supported formats.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

One of the most common format/codec combinatoins currently is mp4/h264/aac. You can use e.g. ffmpeg to transcode your avi file into a compatible mp4:

```
ffmpeg -i {input}.avi -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 {output}.mp4
```